# Does every every non-empty family of non-empty sets have a choice function whose fibers are clutters (sperner families)?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

We call any map $f$ a choice function of the family of sets $\mathcal{K}$ iff $f$ is a map from $\mathcal{K}$ to $(\cup_{S\in\mathcal{K}}S)$ such that $\forall X\in\mathcal{K}(f(X)\in X)$ likewise we call $f$ an anti-choice function of $\mathcal{K}$ iff $f$ is a choice function of $\mathcal{K}$ such that $\small\forall X,Y\in\mathcal{K}(X\subset Y\rightarrow f(X)\neq f(Y))\iff \forall X\in\mathcal{K}(A,B\in f^{-1}[\{f(X)\}]\rightarrow A\not\subset B)$.

Now if $\forall X,Y\in\mathcal{K}(X\not\subset Y)$ then all choice functions of $\mathcal{K}$ are 'anti-choice' functions. But what about other families? Does AC imply all families of non-empty sets have anti-choice functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is entirely inconsistent.

Take $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ to be a family of non-empty sets. Then any choice function must map $\{0\}$ to $0$ and $\{1\}$ to $1$. But now $\{0,1\}$ cannot be mapped to either of its elements.

---

For an example with infinite sets, consider all the initial segments of $\Bbb Q$ except $\varnothing$. There are uncountably many of them (each one defining a unique $r\in\Bbb R$, and $\Bbb Q$ itself), so by cardinality reasons alone uncountably many must have chosen the same element. And since the collection as a whole is a chain, "anti-choice" is necessarily injective, which is impossible.

Comment: Seems I didn't look at many examples. So it wouldn't exist for that family. Sorry for using your time.

Comment: It's a good exercise to play with concepts. It takes time to learn all the "basic rules for forming counterexamples". Don't feel bad, it's part of growing up as a mathematician.

Comment: @bof: Take a chain of order type $\Bbb R$ of subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: There must be some nontrivial questions about finite families, e.g., what if $\mathcal K=\{X\subseteq[n]:|X|\ge k\}$.

Comment: @bof: Yeah, but I'm not great with finite combinatorics. I know the answer when $k=n$.